# Add users to active directory using LDIFDE

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008

Currently I'm facing a problem with adding users to active directory using LDIFDE and dlf file using the below command:

```
ldifde -i -f <filepath> -s <servername>
```

When I tried to add the following user:

```
    dn: CN=sumaya,OU=Ministries,DC=PMOCRM,DC=local
    changetype: add
    objectClass: top
    objectClass: person
    objectClass: organizationalPerson
    objectClass: user
    cn: sumaya
    sn:: 2LnZhNmK
    givenName:: 2LPZhdmK2Kk=
    distinguishedName: CN=sumaya,OU=Ministries,DC=PMOCRM,DC=local
    instanceType: 4
    whenCreated: 20130502061518.0Z
    whenChanged: 20130502061518.0Z
    displayName: sumaya
    uSNCreated: 291424
    uSNChanged: 291428
    name: sumaya
    userAccountControl: 544
    codePage: 0
    countryCode: 0
    accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
    sAMAccountName: sumaya
    userPrincipalName: sumaya@MYGOVTRAINING.AE
    objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=PMOCRM,DC=local
    dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000000.0Z
    mail: alwa@moj.gov.ae
```

It's added successfully

But when I try to add:

```
    dn: CN=CRM AR Test,OU=CRMUsers,DC=PMOCRM,DC=local
    changetype: add
    objectClass: top
    objectClass: person
    objectClass: organizationalPerson
    objectClass: user
    cn: CRM AR Test
    sn: AR Test
    givenName: CRM
    distinguishedName: CN=CRM AR Test,OU=CRMUsers,DC=PMOCRM,DC=local
    instanceType: 4
    whenCreated: 20100316074809.0Z
    whenChanged: 20100316074809.0Z
    displayName: CRM AR Test
    uSNCreated: 16437
    uSNChanged: 16442
    name: CRM AR Test
    userAccountControl: 512
    codePage: 0
    countryCode: 0
    accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
    sAMAccountName: test-ar
    userPrincipalName: test-ar@MygovTraining.ae
    objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=PMOCRM,DC=local
    dSCorePropagationData: 20110606125103.0Z
    dSCorePropagationData: 16010101000001.0Z
```

The following error occurred:

> Add error on entry starting on line 1: Unwilling To Perform
>   The server side error is: 0x52d Unable to update the password. The value provide
>   d for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirem
>   ents of the domain.
>   The extended server error is:
>   0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A120C, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

Would anybody please help me with what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is clear enough: **The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the domain.** - your passwords aren't safe enough.

Your first user has a `userAccountControl` values of 544 - "normal user" with "no password required". So it doesn't require a password -> that's why it works.

Your second user has a `userAccountControl` of 512 - "normal user" and as such it **requires** a valid, strong enough password - and you're not providing one.

So either change the second user's `userAccountControl` to 544 as well - or provide a password that satisfy the requirements set up by the domain admin for this domain.